# Issue with #pragma acc host_data use_device

Tags: mpi, openacc

I'd like the MPI function `MPI_Sendrecv()` to run on the GPU. Normally I use something like:

```
  #pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)
  {
  MPI_Sendrecv (send_buf, N, MPI_DOUBLE, proc[0], 0,
                recv_buf, N, MPI_DOUBLE, proc[0], 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  }
```

And it works fine. However now, I call `MPI_Sendrecv()` inside a loop. If I try to accelerate this loop (with `#pragma acc parallel loop`) or even accelerate the whole routine (`#pragma acc routine`) where the loop and the MPI call are situated, I get an error:

**64, Accelerator restriction: loop contains unsupported statement type

78, Accelerator restriction: unsupported statement type: opcode=ACCHOSTDATA**

How can I make run the call on the device if, like in this case, the call is in an accelerated region?
An alternative could be maybe to do not accelerate the routine and the loop, and use `#pragma acc host_data use_device(send_buf, recv_buf)` alone, but the goal of having everything on the gpu would fail.

EDIT

I removed the #pragma. Anyway, the application runs hundreds of time slower and I cannot figure why.
I'm using nsight-sys to check: [image: here's the pic] Do you have and idea why MPI_Sendrecv is slowing down the app? Now all the routine where it's called is running on the host. If I move the mouse pointer on the NVTX (MPI) section, it prints "ranges on this row have been projected from the CPU on the GPU". What does this mean?
Sorry if this is not clear but I lack of practicality with nsight and I don't know how to analyze the results properly. If you need more details I'm happy to give them to you.
However it seemes weird to me that the MPI calls appear in the GPU section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make MPI calls from within device code.

Also, the "host_data" is saying to use a device pointer within **host** code so can't be used within device code.  Device pointers are used by default in device code, hence no need for the "host_data" construct.

Questions after edit:

> Do you have and idea why MPI_Sendrecv is slowing down the app?

Sorry, no idea.  I don't know what you're comparing to or anything about your app so hard for me to tell.  Though Sendrecv is a blocking call so putting in in a loop will cause all the sends and receives to wait on the previous ones before proceeding.  Are you able to rewrite the code to use ISend and IRecv instead?

> "ranges on this row have been projected from the CPU on the GPU". What
> does this mean?

I haven't seen this before, but presume it just means that even though these are host calls, the NVTX instrumentation is able to project them onto the GPU timeline.  Most likely so the CUDA Aware MPI device to device data transfers will be correlated to the MPI region.

Comment: Thank you Mat, as always. I edited the question because I'm facing some problems removing the host data construct.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding the last point, why you speak about device to device data transfer when the code is running on the host and also the buffer in the MPI calls belong to the host?

Comment: The data transfers are more likely to occur directly from a device to another device via GPUDirect peer-to-peer communication for devices on the same node or GPUDirect RDMA between nodes.   https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/introduction-cuda-aware-mpi/

Comment: I thought that in order to pass GPU buffers to the MPI call the pragma "#pragma acc host_data use_device" is necessary. You're saying that In my case I probably have GPUDirect peer-to-peer communication, even if I didn't add any pragma to handle MPI calls?

Comment: When is useful "#pragma acc host_data use_device" then? I've seen it to be used in a lot of example about CUDA aware MPI.

Comment: The "host_data" directive defines a region in the host code where the device pointer is used and useful for interoperability with native device languages such as CUDA.  For a MPI that's CUDA aware, the MPI calls detect if the pointer is a device or host pointer and then proceed to execute the appropriate underlying code path.  Without "host_data", a host pointer is passed to MPI so CUDA Aware MPI would not be used.